# Altium Top Paste not fully poured

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, altium, layout, solder-paste

In the picture below, Top Paste's 3 of 4 FETs is not poured well. I can't see the reason for this. Any suggestions?

[image: FETs Top Pastes]

Comment: This picture doesn't tell me anything. What copper layer are these attached to if any? Are there PCB heatsinks attached to the pads on purpose? Obviously a big heat sink will mean difficulties with solder wetting as well.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pour" generally refers to polygons of copper on a signal or plane layer. Such polygons have a pour sequence which dictates which ones may be clipped or removed entirely due to a higher-priority polygon pouring earlier. Paste layers are typically the result of pads in footprint or other geometry that dictate, by means of rules, what size the paste geometry will be with respect to the pad it belongs to.

[image: Altium pad with pad stack properties]

In this example, the top paste geometry is shown at right in the Pad Stack properties. In the Shape column, you can see that "Rule Expansion" is selected, which means it will use the Paste Mask Expansion rule within design rules.

Changing this option allows you to override the rule and specify the geometry for the pad directly. It is possible to use values that prevent a paste aperture entirely, which one might do with a test point or fiducial mark.

Check the values for your pads and ensure that they are not somehow preventing a paste mask opening.

Comment: Yes its because of the I don't know how but Pad Stack -> Paste Mask Expansion is manual and -1mm selected. When I correct it with rule I get what I want. Thanks. If I am not wrong actually this setting is not important for my application because of I will use hand soldering?

Comment: You are correct, the paste mask is used when you apply solder paste through a metal mask which is manufactured based on that layer's data. If you are not using solder paste—or more correctly—if you are not using a solder paste _mask_, then you can safely ignore the contents of the layer.